# How deep is the hole in Sparta?

Tags: 300

In Zack Snyder's [300](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416449), when the Persian messenger comes to Sparta to deliver his emperor's message, King [Leonidas](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416449/characters/nm0124930) decides to kill him and his companions by throwing them into a huge hole. It seems to be pretty deep as [one of the men is seen falling for a pretty long time](https://youtu.be/QkWS9PiXekE?t=2m47s) even if it was in slow motion. So, what is the story on the hole? How deep is it?

Comment: I'd think the hole would go all the way to the bottom ;)

Comment: @sirjonsnow, I have to disagree with you there.

Comment: It's a joke, see, because the hole has to have a bottom.

Comment: @sirjonsnow, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhaO9ftZlFo

Comment: It's a bottomless pit. The bottomless pit supervisor makes sure of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I'm sure you are aware, the movie [*300* (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416449/) was not meant to be historically accurate, and was based on a graphic novel rather than an actual history tome.  In reality:

> Darius sent emissaries to all the Greek city-states in 491 BC asking
>   for a gift of "earth and water" as tokens of their submission to
>   him. Having had a demonstration of his power the previous year,
>   the majority of Greek cities duly obliged. In Athens, however, the
>   ambassadors were put on trial and then executed by throwing them in a
>   pit; in Sparta, they were simply thrown down a well. [1]

Since the movie was based on Sparta and their defense of Thermopylae, the messengers were likely thrown in a well.  Wells vary in depth, but I can't imagine it being more than 100 feet or so as there existed no complex machinery at that time to dig very deep.

[1] Taken from the [Wiki page for the Battle of Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae)

Comment: You'd think decomposing bodies would poison the water supply.

Comment: There was actually a well dug up in ancient Greece that contained a [large amount of babies bodies and those of dogs as well](http://www.newsweek.com/2015/06/19/discovery-dead-infants-athenian-well-sheds-light-ancient-greek-society-341681.html).  Apparently they believed the dogs bodies purified the water.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the question literally, I would say **4 meters** deep. The following behind-the-scenes video shows how the scene was shot and how stuntmen fell into a well of depth approximately 4 meters. Fortunately, the bottom was padded.

---

In case the video is removed, here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot from around 20m09s, courtesy of Warner Bros]

As suggested by the [green background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key), [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery) was used to make the well appear bottomless.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I've edited your post, I thought it would be important to give more details. Please feel free to modify. Might be important as well to clarify that the well needs to seem deeper after FX.

Comment: @OldPadawan Thank you. I improved the answer a bit more.

Comment: Seems *really* good now :)